# Ng-repeat angular "2 layer" JSON issue

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am somewhat new to angular and currently I am learning this beautiful framework by making a project for school. But I've encountered  an issue which I can not solve at the moment. I've searched alot on the internet but didn't found something that worked for me.

This is my controller with the JSON included into it

```
(function() {
      app.controller('imageController', function(){

       this.imageList = imageJson;
      });

        var imageJson = [{
            "traveling": [{
                "name": "Kenneth Appiah",
                "label": "pisa",
                "src": "public/media/images/noun/traveling/pisa.svg"
            },
            {
                "name": "Oliver TubeGeometry",
                "label": "eiffel tower",
                "src": "public/media/images/noun/traveling/eiffel.svg"
            },
            {
                "name": "Adriano Gazzellini",
                "label": "colosseum",
                "src": "public/media/images/noun/traveling/colisseum.svg"
        }]
    }];

})();
```

I am using, what I call, a two layered JSON ( just hoping you understand what I mean here :-) ). But for some reason I can not reach these data in my datatags on my HTML. I did some angular basic tutorials and that learnt me how to do this with a json that does not start with something like:

```
    "traveling": [{
            "name": "Kenneth Appiah",
            "label": "pisa",
            "src": "public/media/images/noun/traveling/pisa.svg"
        }]
```

But like this:

```
{
                "name": "Kenneth Appiah",
                "label": "pisa",
                "src": "public/media/images/noun/traveling/pisa.svg"
            }
```

So my assumption would be that my databinding would be something like {{image.traveling.src}}. Image is how I called my ng-repeat. But this didn't work, so I am kind of confused.

This is my HTML (ng-app is also included but its in a differend file)

```
<section class="words">
    <div class="colored-sidebar"></div>
    <!-- content -->
    <div class="previous-button"></div>
    <div class="word-container" ng-controller="imageController as imageCtrl">
      <h1><span>noun</span>words</h1>
      <div class="category-body">
        <p><span>noun</span>traveling</p><hr>
        <div class="category-image" ng-repeat="image in imageList.traveling">
          <img src="{{image.src}}" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </section><!--
--></div>
```

Due to my trial and error I am currently in a tunnel vision. So maybe it something I oversee but I would like to have some positive feedback and criticism on my issue. If I miss any code that is required, let is know I am happy to post it so someone can help me better :-)
I haven't work alot with JSON yet so sorry if its a noob problem

Thanks in regard!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your json object. If you format your json like shown below, it will work.

```
var imageJson = {
            "traveling": [{
                "name": "Kenneth Appiah",
                "label": "pisa",
                "src": "public/media/images/noun/traveling/pisa.svg"
            },
            {
                "name": "Oliver TubeGeometry",
                "label": "eiffel tower",
                "src": "public/media/images/noun/traveling/eiffel.svg"
            },
            {
                "name": "Adriano Gazzellini",
                "label": "colosseum",
                "src": "public/media/images/noun/traveling/colisseum.svg"
            }]
        };
```

Comment: Thanks! I've implented the json inside my code. It does not give any errors so I assume it's alright. Even tho when I look at my console.log I see this:
http://imgur.com/oqAtbCJ

It doesn't even repeat anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: you mean images are not displaying?

Comment: also inject the scope in your controller
 app.controller('imageController', function($scope){

       $scope.imageList = imageJson;
      });

Comment: Thanks alot Dee J! I've managed to let it work thanks to your tip! I may have a last question. Since I created this JSON myself, it is highly possible that I did things wrong. Even though this JSON up there was only a section of it. This is the whole JSON http://jsfiddle.net/6u7q3ar8/. Do you maybe see what I'm doing wrong with creating this JSON so it will work on my angular project? (sorry for bad grammar). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. I will work

```
var imageJson=[{
                "name": "Kenneth Appiah",
                "label": "pisa",
                "src": "public/media/images/noun/traveling/pisa.svg"
            },
            {
                "name": "Oliver TubeGeometry",
                "label": "eiffel tower",
                "src": "public/media/images/noun/traveling/eiffel.svg"
            },
            {
                "name": "Adriano Gazzellini",
                "label": "colosseum",
                "src": "public/media/images/noun/traveling/colisseum.svg"
        }];
```

Use `ng-repeat="image in imageList"`....It will definitely work